# Dynamic ListView several items respond to click

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter that dynamically is changing and expanding content when user clicks a list item. My list also populates as you scroll down.

Here's my problem: whenever i click a list item (at the moment I just change the height of the list item) it works as expected but when I scroll down, more than one list item gets affected. say I click list item with id: 1, then list item with id 1, 7, 15 and so on responds to the touch event, this also happens before the list populates more data so that's not where my problem lies.

MainFragment:

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<EventObject> eo = new ArrayList<EventObject>();
    adapter = new ListAdapterMain(getActivity(), eo);

}
     @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewListFragment);
    lv.setOnScrollListener(onScroll);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    AsyncFetch async = new AsyncFetch();
    async.execute();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(onClickList);

    return rootView;
}

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onClickList = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {

        Log.i("ID", "id: " + id);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lvPars = (AbsListView.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        lvPars.height = 500;
        v.setLayoutParams(lvPars);
        v.requestLayout();

    }
};
```

ListAdapter:

```
    public class ListAdapterMain extends ArrayAdapter<EventObject> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<EventObject> oItems;

public ListAdapterMain(Context context, ArrayList<EventObject> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_mainlist, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.oItems = objects;
}


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null){
    convertView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.list_item_mainlist, null);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.artist = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewListItemArtist);
    viewHolder.venue = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewListItemVenue);
    viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textViewListItemDate);
    viewHolder.bandPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewListItemArtist);
    viewHolder.venuePic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewListItemVenue);

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
}
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

String thisArtist = oItems.get(position).getArtist();
String thisVenue = oItems.get(position).getVenue();
String thisDate = oItems.get(position).getDate();
String thisArtistPic = oItems.get(position).getArtistPic();
String thisVenuePic = oItems.get(position).getVenuePic();

try {
    //Tue, 17 Sep 2013 11:34:01
    Date inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy H:m:s", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(oItems.get(position).getDate());
    DateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    thisDate = outputDate.format(inputDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

holder.artist.setText(thisArtist);

holder.venue.setText(thisVenue);
holder.date.setText(thisDate);
if(!thisArtistPic.isEmpty())
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.bandPic, thisArtistPic);
if(!thisVenuePic.isEmpty())
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.venuePic, thisVenuePic);

return convertView;
    }
       static class ViewHolder{
    TextView artist;
    TextView venue;
    TextView date;
    ImageView bandPic;
    ImageView venuePic;

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the size of the view in onItemClick(), I recommend that do that in getView() in the adapter. Store the position of the view that would be changed, invalidate the ListView and perform the resize in the getView() method instead.